# Numpy or Tensorflow vectorize a sequential operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am wondering if it's possible to vectorize the following operation in Numpy or Tensorflow. The ultimate goal is to do it in Tensorflow, but seems Numpy would be easier for illustration here.

The problem is to get an discretized occupancy grid from a set of 2D points (x, y), and calculate the average of points in that particular grid.

1. Given 2D array `xy`, every row `[x, y]` will be mapped to an index `[xid, yid]`. This step is done via `np.apply_along_axis`
2. In another 3D array `grid_sum`, given the `[xid, yid]` we calculated in 1), we update `grid_sum[xid, yid] += [x, y]`.
3. In yet another 2D array `grid_count`, given the `[xid, yid]` we calculated in 1), we update `grid_sum[xid, yid] += 1`.
4. We get the final results 3D array `grid_mean` by dividing `grid_sum` by `grid_count` at every `[xid, yid]`.

The problem of vectorize this operation is different rows might be trying to write to the same location in the new array, creating a race condition. How can I handle this?

I have the following minimal example here to help understand this situation.

**Edit after comment**

This example works fine because I use a `for` loop. Is it possible to achieve the same without the `for` loop?

```
import numpy as np

xy = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=np.int16)
grid_sum = np.zeros([3, 3, 2])
grid_count = np.zeros([3, 3])

for i in range(xy.shape[0]):
    idx = xy[i]  # simple case, just use array value as index 
    grid_sum[idx[0], idx[1], :] += xy[i]
    grid_count[idx[0], idx[1]] += 1

print(grid_sum)
print(grid_count)

# grid_sum result
# [[[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[0. 0.]
#   [2. 2.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]]

# grid_count result
# [[0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 2. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: I cannot understand the problem _The problem of vectorize this operation is different rows might be trying to write to the same location in the new array, creating a race condition_. Could you please explain more? would grouping by grid not work for you? seems an easier approach without loop. Yet your example seems to be working fine.

Comment: Given containers with row/column indices and values, could you do the following (in numpy, not in tensorflow)?

`A = np.zeros([2, 4])`
`row_idx = [0, 0, 0]`
`col_idx = [1, 2, 3]`
`values = [1, 2, 3]`
`A[row_idx, col_idx] = values`
This will result in A being:
                                                                                             
`[[0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]`